# Is there a way to quickly swap active images for UV maps?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have been looking around for this and haven't really been able to find a definitive answer. I just finished unwrapping a model and am getting ready to bake the Masks and an ambient occlusion map. This model has a lot of different objects a modifiers so I can't exactly combine them into one mesh. Is there a way I can take all the different objects and change the active image for baking on all of them simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Texture Atlas can be of help [enter link description here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?265750-TextureAtlas-create-LightMaps-ShadowMaps-for-entire-scene)